# Is there any generator with $\sqrt{|G|}\leq |X|\leq \frac{|G|}{2}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group of order $\geq 6$. Is there any generator $X$ for $G$ such that $\sqrt{|G|}\leq |X|\leq \frac{|G|}{2}$?

If yes, what about $\sqrt{|G|}< |X|<\frac{|G|}{2}$ (if $|G|\geq 10$)?

**Note** that every subset $X$ with $|X|>\frac{|G|}{2}$ is a generator.

Comment: Could you say what you mean by a *generator*?

Comment: The generating set $X$ for $G$  ($G=<X>$).

Comment: But then the answer to your question is obviously yes. For example, many groups, such as the symmetric groups and the dihedral groups, have generating sets of size $2$. But you can always add extra elements to generating sets, so they also have generating sets of all sizes between $2$ and $|G|$.

Comment: The question is for an arbitrary finite group!, how can we say in general?

Comment: It is complete unclear from the wording of your question whether you are asking if the statement is true for some group $G$ or for all groups $G$. I was also confused because I could not understand the significance of $\sqrt{|G|}$ and of $|G|/2$. Anyway, the answer is yes. In general, for any integer $n$ with $\log_2 |G| \le n \le |G|$, there exists a generating set of $G$ of size $n$.